# Woocommerce: disable free shipping for "cheque payment"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, payment-method

Is it possible to disable in woocommerce the free shipping for "cheque payment"?

My client offers shipping, free delivery and in-store pickup.
Payment methods are paypal, bankwire and cheque.

Once "free shipping" (from €50) is reached, the pickup option disappears and only "free shipping" is displayed.

Can this be turned off?

Unfortunately I haven't found any code snippets or free plugins for it yet.

Comment: There is something overwriting this so check your plugins/ theme functions. In default woocommerce with storefront theme both are available. As for removing shipping based on payment gateway check this - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-gateway-for-specific-shipping-method/

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found a setting yet that might have enabled overwriting. Does anyone have a tip as to what/where this could be?
The logic of all plugins is exactly the opposite of what I need...